# Clean and efficient way to handle file system undo operations in a context manager

Tags: python, assets

I am working on an asset management system for a personal project. My question is how to handle file system operations in python cleanly and efficiently so that I can rollback or undo changes if something goes wrong.

A typical operation might look something like this

```
 try
   file system operation(s)
   update database
 except Exceptions
   undo file system operations already performed
   rollback database transaction
   handle exceptions
```

file system operations can be things like create, copy, link, and remove files/directories

My idea was to have a context manager for both the file system operations and the database management. The execution would be something like this:

```
# create new asset
with FileSystemCM as fs, DatabaseCM as db:

    fs.create_dir(path_to_asset)
    fs.create_file(path_to_a_file_this_asset_needs)
    db.insert('Asset_Table', asset_name)
```

Now if for example db.insert fails the FileSystemCM removes the newly created file and newly created directory, and DatabaseCM rolls back the db transaction

A simple approach to my FileSystemCM implementation would be something like this:

```
class FileSystemCM(object):
    """ File System Context Manager """

    def __init__(self):

        self.undo_stack = [] # list of (fn, args, kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):

        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_val, traceback):

        if exception_type:
            # pop undo actions off the stack and execute
            while self.undo_stack:
                undo_fn, args, kwargs = self.undo_stack.pop()
                undo_fn(*args, **kwargs)

    def create_dir(self, dir_path):

        create_file(dir_path)
        self.undo_stack.append((remove_dir, [dir_path], {'force': True}))

    def create_file(self, file_path):

        create_file(file_path)
        self.undo_stack.append((remove_file, [file_path], {'force': True}))
```

Is there a better approach to this? There are circumstances that this implementation wont handle that I could use feedback on

- deleting files. My thoughts are to move files for removal to a temp location (or create a tmp hard link), if everything goes ok then remove the temp files or links, otherwise revert it back. But this can lead to the situation below.
- the __exit__ code throwing an exception and not finishing the undo operations, perhaps I leave a log file so at least things can be manually cleaned up?

Answer (score 1):

I meant this as a comment but its too long to fit in the comments section. Let me start by saying that this sounds like a very interesting project (at least for my taste).

Sometime ago (I can't remember where) I have read an article post about implementing Undo/Redo functionality, and what they do is maintain two separate stacks (one for undo and one for redo). When the user performs an action a pair of action/its-reverse with their arguments are pushed into the undo stack. Whenever the user performs the undo action the reverse action from the pair is executed and the pair is then moved into the redo stack, and when the redo action is performed the action from the pair gets executed and the pair is taken back into the undo stack.

Whenever the user performs a new action the redo stack is cleared. The only draw back of this approach is the irreversible actions. One way I can think of to overcome that is to use some sort of Event-Sourcing patterns where you keep the whole state of the system and its diff. This might seem very inefficient, but it is used commonly in software.